# Are deleted questions visible?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Title kind of says it all. There was a question I recall a from a few days ago that I'd commented on, but I can't seem to find it so it was likely deleted.

To clarify from a similar question, the question was not my own.

Is it possible to view this question at all or is it completely gone?

Comment: Is it possible the comment you made was simply deleted? I'm not sure if you attempted to find the question by searching for the question itself or by browsing through your comments.

Answer (score 10):

Deleted questions are visible to those [with over 10k rep](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) but only if you have a direct link to it. They do not show up in listings and are not searchable because of the sensitivity of deleted content.

That said, I checked your history: of the comments you've made in the past 2 weeks, none of them were made on a question that is now deleted.

Comment: I wonder if I typed the comment and forgot to post it.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical the comment itself could have been deleted. Deleted comments do not show up in your history (I'm not sure if mods can see it there though).

Comment: The history I looked through includes deleted comments. There are some deleted comments over 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Do you remember what the question was about?